# error trying to install @babel/preset-env

Tags: node.js, npm

i am trying to install @babel/preset-env in node and i am getting the following question

```
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-PMnY0yhKljgjrP3jQNP5C9slQM//bCLO4ZRr9gmo+2mLkVhCIxhT3A9grgblgLXmOPVd6GFzeIEA6/0g99cxDA== integrity checksum failed when
using sha512: wanted sha512-PMnY0yhKljgjrP3jQNP5C9slQM//bCLO4ZRr9gmo+2mLkVhCIxhT3A9grgblgLXmOPVd6GFzeIEA6/0g99cxDA== but got sha512-IU+YnDh7WJASsz892TYz1eQ+vaEypoAPLmu6DO2Uw2NZzfl/F2ypEL3xrEiIXLU8Buok1TujSujt3bLMmUmysg==. (34788 bytes)
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fplugin-transform-member-expression-literals: Integrity verification failed for sha512-PMnY0yhKljgjrP3jQNP5C9slQM//bCLO4ZRr9gmo+2mLkVhCIxhT3A9grgblgLXmOPVd6GFzeIEA6/0g99cxDA== (C:\Users\PRO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\3c\c9\d8d3284a963823acfde340d3f90bdb2540cfff6c22cee1946bf609a8fb698b915842231853dc0f60ae06e580b5e638f55de86173788100ebfd20f7d7310c)
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PRO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-18T22_56_31_231Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one of these solutions

1. `npm cache verify --force`
2. delete `packages-lock.json`
3. `npm cache clean --force`
4. delete `node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this means your local npm cache or your package-lock.json has been corrupted, causing of `@babel/preset-env`'s integrity hash from the npm registry to be different from what you have in your `package-lock.json`. I'd do these steps in this order.

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `rm package-lock.json`
3. `npm cache clean -f`
4. `npm cache verify -f`
5. `npm i`

This should remove any cached data you have and force npm to hit the registry for fresh package data and regenerate your `package-lock.json` to use the updated integrity hash.